# regular expression match case sensitive off

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a regular expression that finds two words in a line.

The problem is that it is case sensitive. I need to edit it so that it matches both the case.

reqular expression

```
^(.*?(\bPain\b).*?(\bfever\b)[^$]*)$
```

Comment: Look at the `IgnoreCase` option [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RegexOptions.Ignorecase` to set case insensitive matching mode. This way you make *the entire* pattern case insensitive. The same effect can be achieved with `(?i)` inline option at the beginning of the pattern:

```
(?i)^(.*?(\bPain\b).*?(\bfever\b)[^$]*)$
```

You can use  the inline flag to only set case insensitive mode to part of a pattern:

```
^(.*?(\b(?i:Pain)\b).*?(\b(?i:fever)\b)[^$]*)$
```

Or you can just match "pain" or "Pain" with

```
^(.*?(\b(?i:P)ain\b).*?(\bfever\b)[^$]*)$
```

Another alternative is using character classes `[Pp]`, etc.

**Note** that you do not have to set a capturing group round the whole pattern, you will have access to it via `rx.Match(str).Groups(0).Value`.

```
^.*?(\b[pP]ain\b).*?(\b[Ff]ever\b)[^$]*$
```

Comment: i was modi fied my regular expression just add an or condition int he regular expression.
^(.*?(\bPain|pain\b).*?(\bfever|Fever\b)[^$]*)$

when i use this programetically:
i iterate according to the number of keys to be matched then make the make the pattern string

patternString.Trim & String.Format(".*?(\b{0}|{1}\b)", pattern(i).Trim,capitaltext(pattern(i))

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.  `[^$]*` means "match characters other than `$` 0 or more times". If you combine the expression with another one, it might not work because the original one is anchored, has $ at the end. You should post the whole code with input text and expected output in the question itself.

Comment: `(\bfever|Fever\b)` is not correct as it will match `feverish` and `qwertyFever`. You should use character class `(\b[Ff]ever\b)`.

Comment: Ah, I seem I got it. Again, I wouldn't complicate it. Use sth like (\b{0}\b)", "[" + pattern(i).Trim().Substring(0,1).ToLower() + pattern(i).Trim().Substring(0,1).ToUpper () + "]" + pattern(i).Trim.Substring(1). Sorry, can't test it now, I am travelling.

Comment: yes it did work for me..thanks every one..appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can usually set a flag for that, depending on your language, or you can mess up your regex into a more ugly looking one using multiple character classes. `[pP][aA][iI][nN]` is essentially the word "pain" without it being case sensitive at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using VB.net, you can tell the regex object to ignore the case sensitivity when you create it

```
     'Defines the pattern
    Dim MyPattern As String = "BlaBla"
     'Create a new instance of the regex class with the above pattern 
     'and the option to ignore the casing 
    Dim Regex As New Regex(MyPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```